# Spyder shows I/O Error when launching in a new Conda environment

Tags: python, spyder

Now I am a beginner, so go easy on me LOL
I am using the newest Anaconda version in Linux. These are my specs:

Anaconda3-2020.07
Python 3.8.5
Ubuntu 20.04
Spyder 4.1.4

I created an environment by trying to clone the Root environment as follows:

```
    $ conda create --name my_env --clone root
```

And this was the response I received...

```
    Source:      /home/pouya/anaconda3
    Destination: /home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env
    The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:
     - conda-forge/noarch::conda-env-2.6.0-1
     - conda-forge/linux-64::conda-4.8.3-py38h32f6830_2
     - conda-forge/linux-64::conda-build-3.19.2-py38h32f6830_2

    Packages: 352
    Files: 5
    Preparing transaction: done
    Verifying transaction: done
    Executing transaction: | b'Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...\n      - Validating: \x1b[32mOK\x1b[0m\n'
    done
    #
    # To activate this environment, use
    #
    #     $ conda activate my_env
    #
    # To deactivate an active environment, use
    #
    #     $ conda deactivate
```

I then activated this new **my_env** environment:

```
    (base) $ source activate my_env
```

Then, I tried launching Spyder in this environment:

```
    (my_env) $ spyder
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 201, in main
        from spyder.app import mainwindow
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 104, in <module>
        from spyder.app.utils import set_opengl_implementation
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/utils.py", line 23, in <module>
        from spyder.utils.qthelpers import file_uri
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/utils/qthelpers.py", line 29, in <module>
        from spyder.config.gui import is_dark_interface
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/config/gui.py", line 28, in <module>
        from spyder.utils import syntaxhighlighters as sh
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/utils/syntaxhighlighters.py", line 20, in <module>
        from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer, bygroups
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygments/lexer.py", line 17, in <module>
        from pygments.filters import get_filter_by_name
      File "/home/pouya/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygments/filters/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from pygments.token import String, Comment, Keyword, Name, Error, Whitespace, \
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 915, in get_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
    OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I tried `spyder --reset` and it didn't work. I updated Conda, Spyder, everything, then tried again, and again exactly the same message. I then switched back to Base(root) and launched Spyder, it was working perfectly well. I can't launch Spyder from this new environment, though. I came across other people's cases where any command in the new environment ends up in an error, but in my case, that's not the issue, Python and Conda are working perfectly well, it's only Spyder that won't launch in this new environment.

What's going on here, and what should I do?

**P.S.** I tried manually installing all those items that couldn't be cloned from the root environment, but it gave me an error telling me those packages couldn't be found in the current channels (including Conda, Conda Forge, Git and Git Hub).

**P.P.S.** I thought maybe this whole duplicating the base thing was wrong, so I made another environment in which only the default packages were loaded. Then, I normally installed Spyder along with all of its dependencies and whatnot, there was no error whatsoever while installing Spyder in this brand new environment, but still, when trying to launch Spyder in this new environment, I still get exactly the same error message, only the name of the directories have been changed according to the name I gave to the environment.

Thanks in advance for any help!